# How is it possible to use 1000 Heroku Dyno hours in one month?

Tags: django, heroku, dyno

I am all set to launch my app and its backend is Django and hosted on Heroku.

As per the Heroku website I will get free 1000 dyno hours but what are these hours, I mean maximum number of hours in a month is 744 so how does it work?

Is it based on number of users using the app or something else?

Answer (score 5):

> As per the Heroku website I will get free 1000 dyno hours but what are these hours, I mean maximum number of hours in a month is 744 so how does it work?

Apps on Heroku can use more than one dyno:

- Some sites might want [more than one web dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling) to handle lots of traffic
- Some might run scheduled jobs, which run on [separate one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos)
- Some might have [background workers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing)

Those hours all add up.